# Bertrand series, not named/standard in English?

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, education

As a French high-schooler/undergrad, I learned about Bertrand series ("séries de Bertrand"), the things of the form
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha \log^\beta n}
$$

as part of the curriculum. They are considered standard, and there is a [Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand) devoted to them (and the results and proofs about their convergence). Since they appear quite often in (counter)examples, I'd argue this is for a good reason.

However, as far as I can tell, they are *much* less common and known in the US (and the UK?). Even on this very website, they appear to be unknown by and large (from a large majority of newcomers), and there is no mention of them on Wikipedia (let alone a page entry for them).

Is there a reason why? Are they not considered useful, or is it that they are known but "the Internet" somehow doesn't reflect this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test mentions them as examples, and also talks about a “generalized Bertrand series”.

Comment: @MartinR Good catch! So, that page talks about Generalized Bertrand series... but never defines Bertrand series. :) (it gives the result on their convergence in passing without naming them)

Comment: The german page https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchysches_Verdichtungskriterium also shows these examples, but does not name them. (I know the series, but never heard the name “Bertrand series” before.)

Comment: Interesting. (Bertrand was French, so there's that... but even in general, naming things helps in referring to them, esp. given it's a *family* of series). @MartinR