# Find the values of a and b for which the series $\sum n^a \cdot (ln(n))^b$ converges absolutely, and for which it diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ for which the series converges absolutely, and for which it diverges.

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{( n^a\cdot(ln(n))^b)}$$

I have compared $$\frac{1}{(n^a\cdot ln(n)^b)} > \frac{1}{(n^a \cdot n^b)}$$

What I see here is that if $a+b>1$ series converges By the $p$ test.
But I need a full range of values for $a$ and $b$ such that it converges and diverges.

Comment: It converges iff either $a>1$ or $a=1$, $b>1$ by Cauchy condensation test.

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3293000/75808

Comment: (also, the reasoning in your last paragraph is wrong - the inequality is in the wrong direction for your argument)

Answer (score 1):

We can think about it$$\int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^{a}}dx$$
When $a>1$,let$$a=1+2\varepsilon(\varepsilon>0)$$
and$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\dfrac{1}{x^{1+2\varepsilon}\ln^bx}}{\frac{1}{x^{1+\varepsilon}}}=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^\varepsilon \ln^bx}=0$$
So$$a>1\implies \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a\ln^bn}\text{converges} $$
$$a<1\implies \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^a\ln^bn}\text{diverges}$$
When $a=1$,we think about it$$\int_{2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x\ln^b x}dx=\int_{\ln2}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^b}dx$$
There are similar ones $$b>1\implies \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln^bn}\text{converges} $$
$$b\leqslant1\implies \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\ln^bn}\text{diverges}$$

Comment: Your implications, as written in the summary, are in the wrong direction. $a>1$ implies that the series converge, not the other way around.

Comment: @Clement C.    Thank you for reminding me. I just got up in the morning. I'm not in a good mood. I'm confused

Comment: To add to this the series converges $a_n = \frac{1}{n (\log n)(\log \log n)^c}$ iff $c \ge 1$; the series $a_n = \frac{1}{n (\log n) (\log \log n)(\log \log \log n)^d}$ if $d \ge 1$, and so on and so forth.